# Reciprocal sum equal to $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given the equation $$1/v + 1/w + 1/x + 1/y + 1/z = 1,$$ where all of $v,w,x,y,z$ are positive integers. One solution is the trivial $1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5$. For distinct solutions with $v<w<x<y<z$ find the minimum of $v+w+x+y+z$.

Comment: What do you mean by the minimum distinct solution? Do you want to minimize $v+w+x+y+z$?

Comment: As far as I know, 25 is the lowest value you can get, but I wouldn't know a formal proof, other than that if one DENOM is decreased by one, another DENOM has to be increased by more than 1, creating a sum more than 25. But admitting, this is no proof

Comment: I think we are looking for the minimum of $x+y+z+u+v$ subject to $\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z+\frac1u+\frac1v=1$ and $(x,y,z,u,v)\ne(5,5,5,5,5)$.

Comment: I think the problem wants all the denominators to be different, then to have minimum sum. A candidate is 2,4,6,18,36.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is the minimum of $s:=x+y+z+u+v$ subject to $x<y<z<u<v$ and $\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z+\frac1u+\frac1v=1$?

From $\frac12+\frac14+\frac17+\frac1{14}+\frac1{28}=1$, we know that $s\le 55$. Hence this is a finite problem.
A quick brute force check of all possibilities with $x+y+z+u+v<55$ reveals that
$$\tag{38} \frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac1{20}=1$$
with $s=38$ is the optimum.

The next solutions with small sums are:
$$\tag{43} \frac12+\frac14+\frac1{10}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{15}=1 $$
$$\tag{45}  \frac12+\frac14+\frac1{9}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{18}= \frac12+\frac15+\frac1{6}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{20}=1  $$
$$\tag{50} \frac12+\frac14+\frac1{8}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{24}=1 $$

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find the minimum $v+w+x+y+z$ subject to $\dfrac1{v}+\dfrac1{w}+\dfrac1{x}+\dfrac1{y}+\dfrac1{z}=1$, here is one way.

From [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we have
$$\left(\sqrt{v}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{v}}+\sqrt{w}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{w}}+\sqrt{x}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{y}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{y}}+\sqrt{z}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{z}}\right)\leq\sqrt{v+w+x+y+z}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac1v+\dfrac1w+\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y+\dfrac1z}$$
From this, conclude that
$$v+w+x+y+z\geq 25$$
And you have the minimum hit for $(5,5,5,5,5)$.

If we want distinct numbers, we then have the following. (Clearly $25$ is a lower bound)
$$(2,4,10,12,15)$$ which adds up to $43$.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect $2,4,8,12,24$ with sum $50$ will be hard to beat, but don't have a proof (yet).

Comment: Answer is 38. I don't know how :'(

Comment: $(2,4,10,12,15)$ beats it by $7$ :)

Comment: Still answer is 38 !

Comment: @user74178:  and it is shown in another answer.

Comment: What about $(3,4,5,6,20)$? It sums to $38$ and solves the equation.

Comment: @DejanGovc:  you are correct.  Hagen von Eitzen posted that a bit ago.  I was working by hand and not creative enough.  In fact he beat me four times.

Comment: Whoops, now how did I miss that? =) Well, now we know.