# Maximum length sub-sequence of probability reciprocals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

Find a non-ascending sequence of non-zero probabilities
$p_1,\dots,p_N$ s.t.

1. the sum of probabilities is $1$ (i.e., a distribution), and
2. maximizes the length of the sub-sequence $1/p_1,\dots,1/p_R$ where the sum is no greater than $N$.

Formally,

maximize $R$

s.t.
$\sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i$ = 1 and
$\sum_{i=1}^{R} 1/p_i \leq N$.

**Observations:**

1. If every $p_i=1/N$ then $R=1$.
2. If $p_i= (1-\varepsilon) / \sqrt{N}$ for $1 \leq i \leq \sqrt{N}$,
   and  $p_i=\varepsilon/(N-\sqrt{N})$
   for $\sqrt{N}+1 \leq i \leq N$,
   then
   $R=(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt{N}$.
   Is this a maximum for $R$?
3. Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279703), can we say that when $R$ is maximized, all $p_i$'s in the sub-sequence are equal?

Answer (score 1):

I found [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/371670) that very closely addresses the problem. 
Based on that, it is easy to see that observation 2 actually gives the maximum for $R$.